# How to make "npx create-react-app" using yarn instead of npm?

Tags: npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

When I command "npx create-react-app" my project installed with npm but I want to my project installing with yarn.
How can I do that?
[now installing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb6ao.png)

[I want to installing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRAWU.png)

Comment: Why not running „yarn create react-app my-app“ in first place?

Answer (score 1):

to select the package manager you have to run either via npx or yarn (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

```
# Run this to use npm
npx create-react-app my-app
# Or run this to use yarn
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Alternatively if you want to stick with npx:

```
npx create-react-app --use-yarn
```

Comment: if i command npm create-react-app my-app it's create with npm 
else if i command yarn create-react-app my-app it's create with yarn both are okay
but my problems is when i command npx create-react-app my-app it's create with npm but i want npx create-react-app my app
create with yarn.
how can i solve it?

Comment: See my alternative solution: npx create-react-app --use-yarn